# No me reproduce la musica si no esta en modo debugger

Tags: java, javasound

Despues de navegar mucho en internet consegui este codigo que me permite ejectutar archivos .wav descargados, el problema es que solo me funciona en modo debugger si le doy a ejecutar directamente no me funciona?

Adjunto el codigo:

```
    playSound();

    }
public static void playSound() {
    try {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\nicoc\\Documents\\GitHub\\PSP\\TrollPSP\\trol1.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
    
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Tira algún error? O Se termina el programa?

Comment: Solo funciona cuando esta en debugger o cuando creo una ventana jframe por ejemplo y ejecuto el codigo es decir dentro del jframe tener ese codigo puesto

Comment: Dices que solo funciona en Debugger, pero ¿qué pasa cuando lo ejecutas directamente? Coloca la excepción que arroja el ``ex.printStackTrace();``

Comment: Al final lo he arreglado, pero no tira ninguna excepcion simplemente es necesario meterlo en un jframe o algo para que se ejecute